# How to use unmanaged dll in .net project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, unmanaged, dllimport

I'm working on an ASP.NET project which generates screen shots. I want to use gdi32.dll in my project. How can I import it?

Comment: I know my question would be sounds strange, but You mentioned what your project generates screen shots. Do you planning to use unmanaged dll on client side or server side?

Comment: I'm trying to generate it server side. I'm struggling with it as I'm not able to find a complete solution which snaps the full/partial page irrespective of the scrollbars, with silverlight/flash controls and without occasional blank images.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use [P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: Additionally, pinvoke.net is a good the source of method signatures.

Comment: @PVitt - Only if you are looking to invoke a Window library.  I would argue there is a far easier method for the author to use besides P/Invoke of course depends what he is taking a screenshot of I suppose.

Comment: @Ramhound - I tried with webbrowser.drawtobitmap() which is not working when the page has silverlight/flash and it is generating blank images frequently. That is why I'm trying with GDI looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If the dll is a system dll, you have to add programatically like this:

`[DllImport("gdi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, 
BestFitMapping = true, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true)]`

And make sure that the project (**Solution Platform**) is set to **32** or **x86** and not to *Any CPU*. You can find more about it with a simple [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&q=unmanaged%20dll%20c%23). Happy 
coding

Answer (score 0):

You could use a C++/CLI wrapper, depending on your requirements.  It makes certain things easier.